# How do I optimize a portfolio that has non-normal distribution?

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

We have used the optimize.portfolio function to calculate our optimal portfolio. The problem we have is that we use alternative assets which do not follow a normal distribution, is it possible to incorporate  a distribution function into the function optimize.portfolio or is there an alternative way to optimize a  portfolio with non-normality assumption. Our code (probably irrelevant) looks something like this:

```
portf <- add.constraint(portf, type="weight_sum", min_sum=1, max_sum=1)
portf <- add.constraint(portf, type = "box", min=c(0.1,0.1,0,0,0,0.3,0.3), max=c(0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3))

portf <- add.objective(portf, type="return", name="mean") 
portf <- add.objective(portf, type="risk", name="ES",arguments=list(p=0.95))

optPort <- optimize.portfolio(hist_returns[,c(1,2,4,10,13,19,20)], portf, optimize_method = "ROI",maxSTARR=TRUE,trace=TRUE)
#We optimized by using the maxSTARR ratio. (return/ES)

chart.Weights(optPort)
weights1 <- optPort[["weights"]]
```

Comment: could you edit the code with the libraries or packages imported. and always mention which programming language you are asking for